# Add "http:// in default href macros

Tags: hyperref

Below link works only for adding "http://" or "https://",
how do I store "http://" or "https://" in the default `\href` macros when "http:" is not in the url link parameter for `\href{}`, url package working fine, but we need automation in \href instead of url package.

Please find MWE file below:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


% The below link works only for adding "http://" or "https://",
% how do I store "http://" or "https://" in the default "\href" macros 
% when there is no "http:" in the "\href{}" parameter?

\noindent \href{www.issgovernance.com/file/policy/active/asiapacific/Australia-Voting-Guidelines.pdf}
{www.issgovernance.com/file/policy/active/asiapacific/Australia-Voting-Guidelines.pdf}

\bigskip
\bigskip
\noindent \href{http://www.issgovernance.com/file/policy/active/asiapacific/Australia-Voting-Guidelines.pdf}
{www.issgovernance.com/file/policy/active/asiapacific/Australia-Voting-Guidelines.pdf}



\end{document}
```

Comment: So how should LaTeX decide whether to add `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  If the URL and the string to be displayed in the document are identical, why not simply load the `xurl` package and write `\url{...}? E.g., why not write `\url{www.issgovernance.com/file/policy/active/asiapacific/Australia-Voting-Guidelines.pdf}`? Doing so would have a very important benefit: URL strings would get line-broken automatically.

Comment: url package right, I cannot break selective or specified word between break, url do that showing link with or without http://, is that possible to do in \href parameters?